# how to disassemble a system call?

Tags: linux, gdb, system-calls, disassembly

How could I disassemble system call, so that i could get the assembly instructions involved in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this. Say I wanted to get an assembly dump of "dup":

Write this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
int main() {
        return dup(0)
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc  -o systest -g3 -O0 systest.c
```

Dump it:

```
objdump -d systest
```

Looking in "main" I see:

```
  400478:       55                      push   %rbp
  400479:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40047c:       bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
  400481:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400486:       e8 1d ff ff ff          callq  4003a8 <dup@plt>
  40048b:       c9                      leaveq
  40048c:       c3                      retq
  40048d:       90                      nop
  40048e:       90                      nop
  40048f:       90                      nop
```

So looking at "dup@plt" I see:

```
00000000004003a8 <dup@plt>:
  4003a8:       ff 25 7a 04 20 00       jmpq   *2098298(%rip)        # 600828 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
  4003ae:       68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  4003b3:       e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400388 <_init+0x18>
```

So it's making a call into a "global offset table", which I would assume has all the syscall vectors. Like the other post said, see the kernel source (or standard library sources?) for details on that.

Comment: The PLT and the GOT are dynamic linker structures. The PLT or Procedure Linkage Table contains indirect jumps (through the GOT) to dynamic functions, and fallback jumps to `dl_runtime_resolve()`. The GOT (Global Offset Table) contains the address of already resolved functions, or the instruction in the PLT following the indirect jump, so it can redirect to the fallback jump.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to do this. System call handling is complex (see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-system-calls/). Since you have tagged this question with "linux", you can just download the source from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) (which will be far more understandable and informative than the assembly code).

Comment: Yes surely the system call implementation can be understood by the code.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding linux system call, browse through the code.

Important files are:

> > /include/linux/syscalls.h (all the supported system calls in linux)
> >
> > /arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S (implementation of system call at register level)
> >
> > /arch/arm/kernel/calls.S (system call numbers)
> >
> > /arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h (address of system call)

**Note: system call table can be addressed only from system.map only.**